# Logon failed for login 'user' due to trigger execution

Tags: sql

I am getting this error randomly on an asp.net web application I have deployed.  I am not using any triggers in the database so I am not sure what to do.  This came up over the weekend when no one was in the application, it just randomly happened.  Please help this is mission critical

This is the first instance of where I get the error:

```
  public static Guid LoginUser
    {
        get
        {
            Guid g = new Guid();
            MembershipUser m = Membership.GetUser();
            if (m != null)
                g = (Guid)m.ProviderUserKey;

            return g;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The 'user' login, is that for the person logging in to the application, or the user that logs into the database on behalf of the user?  I would expect the latter, but I am not certain.

Comment: Seems that somebody has added a logon trigger.

Comment: @James The 'user' login is the database user that the application uses to access the data.

@Martin I have checked against the sys.triggers and there are none on my database...

Comment: @Evan. This would be a server trigger. In `master.sys.server_triggers`

Comment: @Martin - there are no results wheen running select * from master.sys.server_triggers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Login failed comes is generated at the server level, not the database level.

That is, you may have a [LOGON trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326598%28SQL.90%29.aspx). You'd check for this in [sys.server_triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176054%28SQL.90%29.aspx).

Now, there is at least one known issue described on [MS Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/322151/msft-mso-logon-trigger-requires-explicit-permissions-to-be-assigned-for-users-for-its-underlying-objects) as well as some investigation+potential fix by [Pinal Dave](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/06/27/sql-server-fix-error-17892-logon-failed-for-login-due-to-trigger-execution-changed-database-context-to-master/) (YMMV)

Comment: I face this issue when I try to fetch the results through code. I executed this query  **SELECT * FROM sys.server_triggers;** on MSSQL. But it does not receive any records

Answer (score 4):

You could double check for the presence of triggers with:

```
use YourDb
select * from sys.objects where type = 'TR'
```

EDIT: This looks like ASP.NET membership, which ends up in a user database (it's not SQL Server logins.)  Can you see what connection string the ASP.NET membership provider uses?  It's usually in the Web.config, for example:

```
<providers>
  <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"  
      ...
      connectionStringName="<<connection string>>"
```

Comment: Or select * from sys.triggers

Comment: I checked the sys,objects where typer = 'TR' and received back an empty result.  There seem to be no triggers on my database.  What do you mean by the asp.net snipped that is throwing the exception?  I can not even access the site before the error is thrown

Comment: @Evan - look in `master.sys.server_triggers`

Comment: @Andomar - the snippet has been added to the original post on where I first get the error

Comment: @Martin -  there are no results wheen running  select * from master.sys.server_triggers

Comment: @Evan - Are you sysadmin on the machine?

Comment: @Martin - I have admin rights but I am not logged in as sa, the password that worked until friday no longer works for sa...

Comment: @Evan - The definition of `sys.server_triggers` only returns rows meeting the following `has_access('TR', o.id, o.pid, o.nsclass) = 1` so it's possible (likely) that you can't see the logon trigger with your current credentials. Why can't you login as sa? Has the password changed or are you getting the same error about trigger execution? If the password has changed have you been hacked? Or has someone in your company making changes?

Comment: @Martin - I do not think we were hacked and no one in my office has said they made any changes.  Is there a way to override the sa password if I log into the server physically to get in as sa?

Comment: @Evan - If you log into the server using Windows Authentication as an admin then hopefully you should be able to connect. What error message do you see when you try and log in as sa? (I'm trying to establish if the issue is just a buggy logon trigger or something else)

Comment: @Martin - I can log  in with windows authentication just fine, when I try to log in as sa I get a login failed for user 'sa'

Comment: @andomar - My connection string appears fine

Comment: @EvanGWatkins: Then it sounds like IIS gets an error while trying to login to SQL Server. Check out GBN's answer, especially the DAC connection in Pinal Dave's post.

Comment: @martin @Andomar - I got the password by using sqlcmd scripts on the server, when logged in as sa I still do not see any triggers

Comment: @Evan - Very strange. Anything of interest in the default trace? `declare @filepath nvarchar(1000) SELECT @filepath = cast(value as nvarchar(1000)) FROM [fn_trace_getinfo](NULL) WHERE [property] = 2 and traceid=1 SELECT * FROM [fn_trace_gettable](@filepath, DEFAULT) ORDER BY StartTime DESC;`

Comment: @Martin - We have decided to back up everything and restore to a new server, it appears we may have had some unauthorized visitors on the server.... Thanks for all of your help