# SQL Logon Trigger denying userwhen no accounts are being checked/validated

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a very simple logon trigger that simply gets the app name and inserts it into a table in the master db. The trigger does not check or validate any groups, accounts, or users, yet when implemented a few accounts are denied access to the database with the same error:

> 170420.105005 ERROR=13 Logon failed for login [user name] due to trigger execution.Changed database context to [database name]. Changed
>   language setting to us_english.

The trigger:

```
USE master
GO

CREATE TRIGGER Application_Logon_Trigger
ON ALL SERVER 
FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @AppName varchar(100) = (SELECT APP_NAME());

        INSERT INTO master.dbo.loginAuditTable([program_name]) VALUES(@AppName)
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @ErrorNum varchar(20);
        DECLARE @ErrorMessage varchar(max);
        SET @ErrorNum = (SELECT ERROR_NUMBER());
        SET @ErrorMessage = (SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE());
        INSERT INTO dbo.loginTriggerError(ErrorNum, ErrorMessage) VALUES (@ErrorNum, @ErrorMessage);
    END CATCH
END
```

***Note: I have tried 'WITH EXECUTE AS 'sa', as well as using other user contexts, but these do not work, either.

Comment: Possible solution... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803481/logon-failed-for-login-user-due-to-trigger-execution

Comment: What are the permissions on the `dbo.loginTriggerError` and `dbo.loginAuditTable` tables? Also of note, you use a three-part name for one and a two-part name for the other. I'd *guess* that login triggers are executed with master as their database context, but might be worth checking. Also, if all you're trying to do is literally record APP_NAME, extended events might be a better choice (lighter weight, less chance of locking users out of the server).